# Result of Modulo in While loop is false, but not if calculated outside of the loop

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to implement a successive division algorithm in bash
and i'm facing a problem where one of the modulo in the loop return a false result

I tried multiple way of calculating the modulo mainly (( a % b )), expr and bc but all have the same problems

```sh
dec=$1
echo ----Dividing----
echo "dividing $dec by $2"
div=$((dec/$2))
echo "the result is $div"
rem=$((dec%$2))
res="$rem"   
echo " the remainder is $rem"
while [ $div != 0 ]
 do   
   div_old=$div 
   echo "dividing $div by $2"
   div=$((div/$2))
   echo "the result is $div"  
   rem=$(echo "$div % $2" | bc)
   echo " the remainder is $rem"
   if [ $rem != 0 ]
   then
       res="$rem$res"
   else
       res="$div_old$res"
   fi  
   echo "for now the result is $res"
 done
```

$1 = 2371 and $2 = 5

the expected result is 33441 but my script returns 33341

as seen in this output

```
----Dividing----
dividing 2371 by 5
the result is 474
 the remainder is 1
dividing 474 by 5
the result is 94
 the remainder is 4
for now the result is 41
dividing 94 by 5
the result is 18
 the remainder is 3
for now the result is 341
dividing 18 by 5
the result is 3
 the remainder is 3
for now the result is 3341
dividing 3 by 5
the result is 0
 the remainder is 0
for now the result is 33341
33341
```

but when i try to do the same operation outside of the script as

```sh
echo $(echo "94 % 5" | bc)
```

the result is 4 which is good,
any idea of why there is such a difference between inside/outside of the loop ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `echo $(echo "94 % 5" | bc)`?

Comment: There's no need to use `bc`. `echo $((94 % 5))`

Comment: @Barmar I edited my typo with the echo command, and i tried to use different things, but $((94 % 5)) in the loop returns a 3 and not a 4 still

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so you'll see every command executed with variables replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div=$((div/$2))
...
rem=$(echo "$div % $2" | bc)
 ...
```

You are dividing the next `div`, no the old/current/previous one. What you mean is, to divide the old div, to get the new one, and then use the same old_div with `rem`:

```
div_old=$div
echo "dividing $div_old by $2"
div=$((div_old / $2))
echo "the result is $div"
rem=$((div_old % $2))
```

Note that `if [ $rem != 0 ]` is doing string comparison, it doesn't equate numbers. To compare numbers with `[` or `test`, use `-ne`:

```
if [ $rem -ne 0 ]
```

Or just use bash arithmetics expansion:

```
if ((rem != 0))
```

Same with `while [ $div != 0 ]`

Comment: And if you use `set -x`, you'll see it say `++ echo '18 % 5'` when you expect `++ echo '94 % 5'`

Comment: @Barmar Yes thank you for this input too, it is helpful